# How can I save my "customized active input method" after OS reboot in ibus?

Tags: ibus, input-method

In Ubuntu 12.04, using ibus 1.4.1, each time I add input methods into ibus in ibus preferences -> Input Method (I have to tick "Customize active input methods" to edit the list), the list gets cleared after I reboot and logged in again. How can I save the input methods list I made so it doesn't get cleared after reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Am using Ubuntu 12.04 with ibus 1.4.1. Once I setup the input methods, they stay across reboots and are working fine.

1. Is the ibus-daemon running after your reboots?
  ```
  $ ibus-daemon 
  current session already has an ibus-daemon
  ```
2. Did you make sure you are in an editable environment (somewhere you can type) when checking if the input methods are available?

Update:
The keyboard (ibus tray) icon does not appear in my menu bar any more.  But was still able to use the shortcut key to switch among the input methods (default Alt-Shift_L) and disable (Ctrl-space).

Comment: +1. It happens to me as well and I got to the same conclusion, if you find the way to make the icon show up again please write it here. I will do the same. In case it makes any difference, I'm with Japanese (Japanese-Anthy)